# Issue with BeautifulSoup: Some Image URLs Returning as None Despite `src` Attribute Presence

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, html-parser

I am using **BeautifulSoup** to extract image URLs from an HTML structure in Python. The HTML structure contains several `<img>` tags with the `src` attribute. I've implemented the `_get_images` function, which uses BeautifulSoup's `find_all("img")` method to retrieve the image URLs. However, I'm facing an issue where some image URLs are returning as `None` even though the `src` attribute is present in the HTML.

Here's my `_get_images` function:

```py
def _get_images(self, soup):
    article_images = []
    images = soup.find_all("img")

    for img in images:
        src = img.get('src')
        article_images.append(src)

    return article_images
```

The output I get shows that some URLs are `None`, while others are correctly retrieved. I have checked the HTML structure, and the `<img>` tags do contain the `src` attribute. What could be causing this problem, and how can I resolve it to fetch all the image URLs correctly?

What could be causing this problem, and how can I resolve it to fetch all the image URLs and titles correctly? My goal is to have a list of URLs, where each URL contains the `src` the image, and to ensure that no `None values` are present in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly the ***img*** elements are dynamic elements.

---

### Solution

To extract the values of *`src`* attribute from the `<img>` elements you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447) and you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

Code block:

```
def _get_images(self):
    article_images = [my_elem.get_attribute("src") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.TAG_NAME, "img")))]
    return article_images
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!  Your solution worked perfectly, and I was able to successfully extract all the image URLs with `src` attribute.  I really appreciate your expertise and assistance in resolving the issue.  Thanks again for taking the time to help me out!